# pyautogui.leftclick and or rightclick doesnt work

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui, time

time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.moveTo(x=960, y=540)
pyautogui.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.rightClick
```

For some reason, the rightclick doesnt work idk pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of moving it first and clicking you have to do

```
  import pyautogui, time

  time.sleep(5)
  pyautogui.rightClick(x=960, y=540)
```